# Binning velocity data then averaging it

Tags: python, numpy, binning

So I am running a simulation where particles are interacting with each other and the walls. Here is the snippet that has been writing the particle data (number of timesteps, velocity-x, velocity-y, velocity-z, position-x, position-y, position-z) to individual files for each particle over a large amount of time steps (incremented by 1000). Right now I have 15 particles but in the future there will be more.

```
N_max = sim.getNumTimeSteps()
particleData = [ [] for x in range(len(sim.getParticleList()))]
for n in range (N_max):
    sim.runTimeStep()
    if (n%1000==0):
        particles = sim.getParticleList()
        for i in range(len(sim.getParticleList())):
            x, y, z = particles[i].getVelocity()
            x2, y2, z2 =  particles[i].getPosition()
            particleData[i].append( (n, x, y, z, x2, y2, z2) )
for i in range(len(sim.getParticleList())):
    with open("{0:d}.dat".format(i), "w") as f:
        for j in particleData[i]:
            f.write("%f : %f,%f,%f : %f,%f,%f \n" % (j[0], j[1], j[2], j[3], j[4], j[5], j[6]))
sim.exit()
```

In my simulation, the top wall is fixed and the bottom is sheared (moving). I am interested in dividing my simulation into strips based on y-position. So if it is 10 units in the y direction, I want to split it into 10 strips of 1-width. I am trying to collect the speeds of particles throughout these strips (to compare speeds depending on proximity to which wall), which I will then later average and graph with matplotlib.

I am very new to Python, so someone very good at it recommended I use binning. IE for each time step, after reading the particle position and velocity, I should check where that particle's y-position is. How do I bin like that--adding it to a list of particles for each bin? And they recommended storing the average information in another array. I've Googled plenty on binning but I'm overwhelmed by all the things that numpy and scipy can do so these complicated/advanced examples are lost on me. Is this the best way to go about it? Does this all make sense?!

This is as far as I've gotten with reading the particle's data...

```
for i in range(10):
    with open("{}.dat".format(i),'r') as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        y2 = []
        for row in data:
            y2.append(float(row[5]))
```

then I'm assuming the binning happens, putting y2 in between certain values? like `if (n / 10) <= y2 <= ((n+1) / 10):`?

Here is an example of the dat files:

> 0.0 : 0.999900,-0.999900,0.0 : -6.999000,-7.001000,0.0 
> 1000.0 : -1.617575,-0.927360,0.0 : -6.032388,-9.007120,0.0 
> 2000.0 : -1.019145,-0.939388,0.0 : -3.059924,-9.008897,0.0 
> 3000.0 : 0.654350,-0.560711,0.0 : -4.575242,-9.242543,0.0 
> 4000.0 : 0.592084,0.509928,0.0 : -3.952575,-9.275643,0.0 
> 5000.0 : 2.288733,0.0,0.0 : -3.038456,-10.0,0.0
> etc until end of simulation, n=20000

---

- Each file belongs to an individual particle, so it shows that particle's movement and speed across the timesteps.
- I am simulating 15 particles so I have 15 files.
- For the strips I want all the particles are in that strip at any time.

  - I will average those numbers later.
- If the simulation's domain is 10x10, the particles are anywhere between y=0 and y=10.

Comment: Can you give an example of `1.dat` and `2.dat`? Does `1.dat` contain the *time history* data of particle one? `trying to collect the speeds of particles throughout these strips`: for *strip x* do you want all the particles that are in that strip at any time? or will there be a *strip x* for each time that contains the particles that are in that strip at that specific time? If the range of y values is fixed, what is it? (a particle has to be between 0 and ? from something)?

Comment: I edited my post to include a sample of a dat file. Each file belongs to an individual particle, so it shows that particle's movement and speed across the timesteps. I am simulating 15 particles so I have 15 files. // 
For the strips I want all the particles are in that strip at any time. I will average those numbers later. // 
If the simulation's domain is 10x10, the particles are anywhere between y=0 and y=10. So bins at increments of 1 or 2, ie 0-2, 2-4, 4-6, 6-8, 8-10 would be useful? Or being able to divide it by any number I want in case the domain changes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-[Pandas,Numpy,SciPy] solution. If at some point in the future processing time becomes annoying you could delve into those - there is a learning curve. There are other advantages particularly with Pandas - subsequent analysis might be easier with Pandas - But you can probably do all analysis without it.

> - For the strips I want all the particles are in that strip at any time.

You will need to identify each data point after you have lumped them all together. For simplicity I've used a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to make an object of each data point.

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple
Particle = namedtuple('Particle',('name','t','x','y','z','x2','y2','z2'))
```

Often choosing the correct container for your stuff is important - you have to figure that out early and it affects the mechanics of the processing later. Again I've opted for simplicity with no thought of how it will be used later - a dictionary with key/value pairs for each strip. Each key is the *left-edge* of the strip/bin.  Converting the y position to an integer easily categorizes it.

```
# positions in example data are all negative
bins = {-0:[],-1:[],-2:[],-3:[],-4:[],-5:[],-6:[],-7:[],-8:[],-9:[]}
```

Use the csv module to read all the files; make Particles; put them in bins.

```
for name in range(3):
    with open(f'{name}.dat') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=':')
        # example row
        # 0.0 : 0.999900,-0.999900,0.0 : -6.999000,-7.001000,0.0
        for t,vel,pos in reader:
            t = float(t)
            x,y,z = map(float, vel.split(','))
            x2,y2,z2 = map(float, pos.split(','))
            p = Particle(name,t,x,y,z,x2,y2,z2)
            y = int(p.y2)
            #print(f'{y}:{p}')
            bins[y].append(p)
```

---

Partial `bins` made from some random data.

```
{-9: [Particle(name=1, t=1000.0, x=1.09185, y=2.13655, z=-1.96046, x2=-8.74504, y2=-9.89888, z2=-9.49985),...],
 -8: [Particle(name=0, t=5000.0, x=1.2371, y=1.10508, z=-0.9939, x2=-9.47672, y2=-8.90004, z2=-8.06145),
      Particle(name=2, t=7000.0, x=-0.82952, y=0.14332, z=-0.3446, x2=-2.76384, y2=-8.14855, z2=-7.2325)],
 -7: [...,Particle(name=2, t=12000.0, x=1.06694, y=0.02654, z=-2.93894, x2=-8.62668, y2=-7.93497, z2=-6.18243)],
 -6: [Particle(name=0, t=3000.0, x=0.01791, y=-2.67168, z=-1.39907, x2=-6.00256, y2=-6.64951, z2=-6.35569),...,
      Particle(name=2, t=18000.0, x=2.41593, y=-2.27558, z=-1.1414, x2=-6.90592, y2=-6.42374, z2=-9.67672)],
 -5: [...],
 -4: [...],
 ...}
```

---

Random data maker.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
def make_data(q=3):
    for n in range(q):
        data = np.random.random((21,6))
        np.add(data, [-.5,-.5,-.5,0,0,0], out=data)
        np.multiply(data,[6,6,6,-10,-10,-10],out=data)
        np.round_(data,5,data)
        t = np.linspace(0,20000,21)
        data = np.hstack((t[:,None],data))
        with open(f'{n}.dat', 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=':')
            writer.writerows(data.tolist())
```

---

If in the future you want finer strips, say hundredths of units, just multiply by that factor.

```
>>> factor = 100
>>> y2 = -1.20513
>>> int(y2*factor)
-120
>>> d = {n:[] for n in range(0,-10*factor,-1)}
>>> d[int(y2*factor)].append(str(y2))
>>> d[-120]
['-1.20513']
>>>
```